# Got an 11-week male lab puppy. We live in NY city apartments and I am not sure if he has received any shots. I have a few questions

Tags: dogs, diet, toilet-training, vaccination

My wife and I got a new male lab puppy, who is living with us in our apartment. I have a few questions, I would really appreciate if you could me out here.

**Issue:**

Not sure if the puppy has received his first shot.
I got this puppy from a friends acquaintance, who lives on a farm in PA and had a litter. When asked for medical records he showed me the vaccination record for a female puppy, but not for the one we got and said that our puppy got the exact ones. No document makes me anxious.

Questions:

1. Can I take him out for a walk or to potty train? Is there a risk of catching viruses?
2. Let's assume he has been vaccinated.. then if I take him to the vet
   and they vaccinate him, is that safe for the pup?
3. He does not poop on the wee wee pads .. how do I get him to do this?

I don't have any family members who have ever had a pet. I've never had a pet. please help... Thank you

Leo the good boy:
https://imgur.com/gallery/lSj9mLg

Comment: Hi Nodnin. Welcome to Pets.SE! Your question _might_ get flagged as "Too broad". I'd recommend keeping the vaccine-related stuff in this post (including walks and potty train) but move the the water and feeding to another question.

Comment: @Roflo Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

owner,

Congratulations on the new pupper, first of all! Good luck with those male labs, mine is a chewer but I love him more than anything. Anyway....

1. In my opinion I would get him to the vet asap and get their opinion. I think that it really is a judgement call as far as who your friend is because there really is no physical records. What I mean is, if he seems like the guy that would cheap out and not get the vaccines for all of the puppies, see what I am getting at?
2. We switched vets for my guy after his first round of shots and they had trouble confirming with the old vet just exactly what he had. They pretty much told us that anything that wasn't dangerous to double-up on they would give him. We were just extra cautious for anything that they couldn't get him which was something about water-borne bacteria so no standing in puddles, keep the water bowl clean, etc.
3. And I am sorry, but LMFAO. My pup (Oscar) hated those things, pooped next to it then shredded the pad. I ended up getting what was called a Wee-Wee Patch which is sturdier and washable so he didn't chew it and every time he began to have an accident my partner or I quickly dragged him over to it and rewarded him for staying on it. (Yeah, pee got EVERYWHERE), but he's fully trained now after transitioning form the pads to outside when he began to pee on them.

*EDIT* Just saw the pic of Leo on Imgur and gahhhhh so cute! And hope I could help!

Comment: Cute pup. I concur with taco on all points. Vet-shots-clean-wee patch, the plastic grass washable one. Good luck 